# Replace every " within string

Tags: sed

I have lines in a text file which looks like this example:

```
"2009217",2015,3,"N","N","2","UPPER DARBY FIREFIGHTERS "PAC"","","","","7235 WEST CHESTER PIKE","","UPPER DARBY","PA","19082","","6106220269",4245.0100,650.0000,.0000
```

I want to replace every double quote in multiple partial strings similar to this `"UPPER DARBY FIREFIGHTERS "PAC""`across the whole file.

So the result should be as below for each instance of the recurring double quotes:

```
"2009217",2015,3,"N","N","2","UPPER DARBY FIREFIGHTERS PAC","","","","7235 WEST CHESTER PIKE","","UPPER DARBY","PA","19082","","6106220269",4245.0100,650.0000,.0000
```

I came to this sed line:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\1\2\3/"
```

But now I don't know how to replace the double quote within `\2`.

Is that possible with `sed`?

Comment: Put a backslash in front of it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, that is correct

Comment: You forgot the `\1` and `\3` in your replacement

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Also, instead of doing `cat file | sed ...`, you can do `sed ... file`. Later it will make it easier to use the `-i` flag to do the transformation in-place.

Comment: There are many CSV dialects but most of them double the double quotes to quote them (sic). Backslash isn't an escape character at all in these dialects.

Comment: @tripleee I updated the example. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Your data is not valid CSV. Can you give some more examples? Is `"XXX"` always at the end of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use `awk` for that because it is more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
BEGIN {
    # Use ',' as the input and output field delimiter
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    # Iterate through all fields. (NF is the number of fields.)
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # If the field starts and ends with a '"'
        if($i ~ /^".*"$/) {
            # Replace all '""
            gsub(/"/,"",$i)
            # Wrap in '"' again
            $i = "\"" $i "\""
        }
    }
}
print
```

Comment: You’ve nailed it. AFAICT your regex can’t be simpler.

Comment: What should `1,"a "b" c",""` return?

Comment: @potong Good catch! I removed the sed version

Comment: @thewhtmba I removed the sed version, there was a problem which potong found.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thank you, I've implemented the `awk` answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^((([^",]*,)*("[^",]*",([^",]*,)*)*)"[^",]*)"([^,])/\1\6/;ta' file
```

This removes extra double quotes from strings surrounded by double quotes and delimited by `,`'s.

It does this by eliminating properly constructed double quotes strings and non-quoted strings (in this example numbers) and then removes double quotes that are not followed by `,`

```
[^",]*,                            # non double quoted strings
"[^",]*",                          # properly quoted strings
(([^",]*,)*("[^",]*",([^",]*,)*)*) # eliminate all properly constructed strings
"[^",]*"([^,])                     # improper double quotes
       ^
       |
```